# How to install selenoid on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, google-chrome, selenoid

I don't understand how can I install selenoid on Windows 10. 
I'm using this tutorial:

```
https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/blob/master/docs/selenoid-without-docker.adoc
```

I've downloaded last version of selenoid (v1.7.1) for Windows here

```
https://github.com/aerokube/cm/releases/tag/1.7.1
cm_windows_amd64.exe
```

I've dovnloaded chromedriver.eve (v 77)
I've created browsers.json configuration file:

```
{
  "chrome": {
    "default": "77",
    "versions": {
      "77": {
        "image": ["C:\\Users\\AnastasiiaBondarenko\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe", "--log-level=DEBUG"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've put next command into PowerShell:

```
./selenoid_windows_amd64.exe -conf ./browsers.json -disable-docker
```

**When I'm trying now to open selenoid hub page it shows me 404 error:**

[image]

**I expected to see smth like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) This 404 error comes from Selenoid, meaning there is no such API `/` in Selenium protocol. In the next release opening `/` will be showing Selenoid version (as this behavior is frequently confusing new users).

2) On Windows with installed Docker you don't have to create configuration files manually. Just download CM binary and run it as follows:

```
> cm selenoid start
```

This command will download and generate the rest.

Feel free to contact us in Telegram [channel](https://t.me/aerokube) if something does not work.

Comment: Dear Vania,

As I understand "cm" in my case will be "./selenoid_windows_amd64.exe"
So, when I'm trying to run this:

` ./selenoid_windows_amd64.exe selenoid start` 

It gives me an error:
`[C:\Users\AnastasiiaBondarenko\Downloads\selenoid_windows_amd64.exe: browsers config: read error: open config/browsers.json: The system cannot find the path specified.]`

Answer (score 0):

**Download latest Selenoid binary from**

https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/releases

**Download some IEDriverServer archive from**

```
http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

and unpack it to some directory (i.e on C disk)

**Create browsers.json configuration file in the folder with name config:**

```
{
      "internet explorer": {
      "default": "11",
       "versions": {
       "11": {
       "image": ["C:\\IEDriverServer.exe"]
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

**From command line execude command :**

```
selenoid_windows_amd64.exe -conf config/browsers.json -disable-docker
```

**Don't forget to add some changes in your code see :**

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
          capabilities.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
          capabilities.setVersion("11");

          driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
            URI.create("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub").toURL(),
            capabilities
        );
```